# Problem with converting NVARCHAR column to DATE datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `nvarchar` column `AddDate` and I tried to use `alter column` to convert it to `date`, but I get this error

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

My data looks like this

```
AddDate
---------------------
10/2/2019 1:06:00 AM
10/28/2019 3:53:00 PM
Mar  6 2020  6:17PM
Feb 20 2020 12:08PM
10/4/2019
10/4/2019
```

Not sure a possible way to convert them to dd-mm-yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: The problems here is that you're storing dates as a `nvarchar`, and secondly that they are inconsistent formatted. You don't have any other *real* choice but to fix your data manually. And then for values like `10/4/2019` you're going to have to guess if that's 10 April 2019 or 4 October 2019, or consult the original data source. This is just a couple of reasons why storing dates as a `(n)varchar` is a ***really*** bad idea.

Comment: On your closing statement of *"Not sure a possible way to convert them to dd-mm-yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy"* Date and Time data types don't have a format, they are stored as binary values. Formatting should be done in the presentation layer.

Comment: So I guess need to manually change to mm/dd/yyyy and then alter the column to date format. Thank you all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try_convert()` will work with the sample data.

`try_convert()` will return a NULL value if the conversion fails.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([AddDate] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('10/2/2019 1:06:00 AM')
,('10/28/2019 3:53:00 PM')
,('Mar 6 2020')
,('Feb 20 2020 12:08PM')
,('10/4/2019')
,('10/4/2019')

Select * 
      ,AsDate   = try_convert(date,AddDate)
      ,AsString = format(try_convert(date,AddDate),'dd-MM-yyyy')
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
AddDate                 AsDate      AsString
10/2/2019 1:06:00 AM    2019-10-02  02-10-2019
10/28/2019 3:53:00 PM   2019-10-28  28-10-2019
Mar 6 2020              2020-03-06  06-03-2020
Feb 20 2020 12:08PM     2020-02-20  20-02-2020
10/4/2019               2019-10-04  04-10-2019
10/4/2019               2019-10-04  04-10-2019
```

Comment: Problem here is the formats are effectively best guesses. You have no way of knowing if `10/2/2019 1:06:00 AM` should be `2019-10-02T01:06:00` or `2019-02-10T01:06:00` and making the wrong assumption can be costly. Considering the OP wants `dd-MM-yyyy` I would *expect* that `10/4/2019  ` is `2019-04-10`, but that means that `10/28/2019 3:53:00 PM` makes no sense.

Comment: @Larnu Agreed, but looking at the sample data, it leans towards MDY.  I know that "across the pond" you have suffer with every format under the sun  :)

Comment: I have about 200,000 records like this so unable to use insert.

Comment: @Tsang The (at)YourTable is just a demonstrative table variable.

Comment: If you can show me replace to Mar 6 2020 to  3/6/2020 then I can do it manually

Comment: @Tsang I would suggest that you ADD a date column and UPDATE YourTable set NewDateCol = try_convert(date,AddDate)      This is assuming your data is MDY.   Any item where the new column is NULL, the conversion failed.   This is the risk of storing dates as strings

Comment: OMG. It works. None of them failed. Thank you so much @John Cappelletti. I owe you a cup of coffee.

Comment: @Tsang Always happy to help

Comment: My apologize. I must so happy and forgot it.